# Evaluating dynamic properties

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have an object that inherits from `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`. When I'm debugging in Visual Studio, the Watch window shows "Dynamic View" which requires expanding to evaluate.

How can I do the same thing, in code--how can I take a dynamic `myThing` and get an object or dictionary from it that contains all the dynamic properties/values that are in `myThing`?

Answer (score 2):

If `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` implementation can provide the dynamic member names, you can get them.

It works for `ExpandoObjects` and `DynamicObjects` and any other `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` who provides a meta object with an implementation of `GetDynamicMemberNames()`.

Try this:

```
var properties = new List<string>();
dynamic dynObject = new ExpandoObject();

dynObject.Prop1 = "property value 1";
dynObject.Prop2 = "property value 2";

var provider = dynObject as IDynamicMetaObjectProvider;

if (provider != null)
    properties.AddRange(provider.GetMetaObject(Expression.Constant(dynObject)).GetDynamicMemberNames());

foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Ah, so I have to enumerate the properties via `GetDynamicMemberNames` then. Hmm, I was hoping there was some extension method somewhere in .NET that would just give me entire object as an anonymous `object`.